# How to compare user input with the keys of a dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, input, compare

I am trying to figure out how to compare my input with the keys of a dictionary. I want to print out the matching words with the dictionary and their value. It would be nice if someone could spent some time to help me with my issue:

```
dictionary = {"nice":"0.5012", "awesome":"0.5766", "thankfull":"0.5891"}

def PNV(saysomething):
    for token in nlp(saysomething):
        while True:
            if token in dictionary:
                print("the word", key, "is same as" + str(token) + 'with the value' + dictionary[value])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dictionary = {"nice":"0.5012", "awesome":"0.5766", "thankfull":"0.5891"}

def PNV(saysomething):
    for token in nlp(saysomething):        
       if token in dictionary:
            key = str(token)
            value = str(dictionary[token])

            print("the word", key, "is same as" + str(token) + 'with the value' + value)
```

---

**EDIT**
Based on OP comments

```
dictionary = {"nice":"0.5012", "awesome":"0.5766", "thankfull":"0.5891"}

def nlp(x):
    return x.split()

def PNV(saysomething):
    for token in nlp(saysomething):
        if token in dictionary:
            key = token
            value = dictionary[token]            

            print("the word '{key}' is same as '{token}' with the value {value}".format(key = key, token = token, value = value))


PNV('trying to get a nice result, this is awesome')
```

produces

```
the word 'nice' is same as 'nice' with the value 0.5012
the word 'awesome' is same as 'awesome' with the value 0.5766
```

Comment: thank you for your fast reply Caverac. Unfortunately I don't get a result when I try it like that

Comment: @Yedolin What do you get?

Comment: I enter "PNV("trying to get a result")" in the shell but nothing happens. I import NLP and spacy if this matters!

Comment: @Yedolin What is the function `nlp` supposed to do?

Comment: It's spliitting the sentence into single tokens

Comment: @Yedolin I see, you are not getting anything because the string you enter does not have any of the tokens you are looking for. Try something like `PNV('trying to get an nice result, this is awesome')`

Comment: thank you. I tried that too but it's still not giving a result

Comment: ok then something was wrong with my imported function. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Now I'll assume that `nlp()` returns a list of words like strings and that you simple look if the passed phrase there is a word that your internal script have a different meaning/value for. Correct me if is not the case.

With the preceding assumpions you can do the following:

```
dictionary = {"nice":"0.5012", "awesome":"0.5766", "thankfull":"0.5891"}

def PNV(saysomething):
    for token in nlp(saysomething):
        if token in dictionary:
          #because token is the key I removed the dupplication in print
          print("The word", token, "for me has the following value" + dictionary[token])

text = input("Write some interessting facts: ")
PNV(text)
```

However, if you want to say that some words/tokens for your program have some equivalents that are the keys in the dictionary than the simple conditional isn't sufficient.
A simple approach in this specific case will be to use another dictionary with equivalents/synonyms and check first this one to retrieve the synonyms and use them for printing in the following way..

```
dictionary = {"nice":"0.5012", "awesome":"0.5766", "thankfull":"0.5891"}

def getSynonyms(word):
  """Takes a word and returns some synonyms that the program knows"""
  knowledge = {"fantastic":["awesome","wonderful"],
              "good": ["nice","normal"]}

  if word in knowledge: #the word is present
    return knowledge[word]
  else:
    return None

def PNV(saysomething):
    for token in saysomething.split(" "): #using split to simulate npl()
      synonyms = getSynonyms(token)
      words = [token]
      if synonyms:
        words.extend(synonyms) #words and its synonyms
      for word in words:
        if word in dictionary: 
          print("The word", token, "is same as " + word + " with the value " + dictionary[word])

PNV("Hi good day")
```

Obviously there are some disadvantages with this simple approach, but for simple usage will do.